# set button background image size (java code)

Tags: android, image, button, background, scale

i have created a dynamic buttons to popolate my main activity.
Buttons works fine.
But im looking to set a image background.

i have tested everything but the result of img is so bad.

How to scale image perfect to the size of button?

i have tested this but not work beacause getWidth give me errore >0

```
        int newWhidt=button.getWidth();
        int newHeight=button.getHeight();
        Bitmap originalbitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.trasparent);
        Bitmap scaleBitmap= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalbitmap,newWhidt,newHeight,true);
        Resources resource=getResources();
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(resource, scaleBitmap));
```

this is my code

```
    private void creabottoni(){
    TableLayout table=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableforbuttons);
for(int row=0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++){
    TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            1.0f));

    table.addView(tableRow);


    for(int col=0;col < NUM_COL; col++){
        final int FINAL_COL=col;
        final int FINAL_ROW=row;
        //Drawable immagine= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trasparent);
        final int FINAL_ID=buttonid;// creo FINAL_ID PER PASSARE ID A ACTIVITY OPERATORE
        Button button=new Button(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                1.0f));


        Cursor res =myDB.getnamebyidbutton(buttonid);
        buttonid++;
        res.moveToFirst();


        //**********METTO TESTO BOTTONI FUNZIONA RES DBHELPER****************************************************
        button.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("NOME")));




        //qui controllo quale bottone ho premuto

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                bottonepremuto(FINAL_ID);


            }
        });



    }//fine ciclo colonna
}//fine ciclo riga

}//fine creabottoni
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the project view of your project display and in the various images packages i.e:hdmi,xhdmi,xxhdmi,etc. put the same image of different sizes with the same name the in the xml just reference it as drawable/"name of image"

Answer (score 0):

You Better use 9-patch background.
And set background in your java file like

`button.setBackground(your 9-patch);`

[tutorial for 9-Patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use **ImageButton** instead of **Button** if you want to give clickability.

If you use **ImageButton** you can use following code to set image resource

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

For graphics i would recommend Vectors instead of images.

[Vector Asset Studio Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html)

[image: Vector Asset Studio In Android Studio]